# With ngx-datatable, Is it possible to have one column headers for two columns?

Tags: angular, ngx-datatable

I'm trying to create an ngx-datatable column.  I need a single column header for two columns (Please see screenshot).  Is this possible?

[Example screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sgW2j.png)

Comment: What I ended up doing was having the second column have a blank header and removing the border.  Not a work-around I was thrilled with, but it worked,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, canonical `rowspan / colspan` is not there with `ngx-datatable`, but one can either:

- Pre-format the data accordingly, like: `item.data1 + " " + item.data2`
- Use templates as in [this example](http://swimlane.github.io/ngx-datatable/#inline).

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-datatable/issues/528) and [here](https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-datatable/issues/407) are two links to people requesting this functionality. Looks like this was a feature that a lot of people have been asking for, but `ngx-datatable` has lost momentum with keeping up with feature requests. If the feature is absolutely required, I would try to find a different library, or create your own wrapper around ngx-datatable.